# Outdoor light fixture not working

Tags: electrical, switch, light-fixture

I am a newbie with anything electrical so please forgive my ignorance. All of a sudden, my front porch light fixture stopped working. Changing the light bulb didn’t work so I’m trying to figure out if it’s the fixture, the switch or the wiring. I tried installing a new fixture but got a pop and flash and it didn’t work (it’s possible I connected it wrong since I was having trouble getting the wires connected with the wire nuts). So I just put the old fixture back in for now (nothing looks corroded on the fixture).

The box that contains the switch for the exterior light also contains a 3 way switch for my foyer light. The only thing i noticed on the switch is that the ground wasn’t connected- is that an issue? I just replaced the switch (hot, neutral and ground) and bought a multimeter. When I test between the hot and the ground on the new switch, I’m getting 120V. When I test between what I believe to be the neutral and the ground when switch is off I get 0...when switch is on, it reads 120V. When I test between the neutral and the hot, I’m always seeing 0V. I thought this was odd- isn’t there supposed to be voltage when touching the probes to the neutral and hot? Can someone clarify this for me? Thanks in advance. Should I turn off the breaker, pull off the fixture outside and flip the breaker back on and test the wires outside to see if it’s making it outside?[image][image][image][image]

Comment: @Harper I should clarify - I did shut off the circuit breaker when I was installing the fixture. I only heard the pop when I flipped the switch on after the installation was done.

Comment: oh! Well your technique was fine then, my apologies.  Visible arc flash *inside a switch* is disconcerting, it indicates a dead short somewhere,  what event "took out" the light originally?

Comment: I may be overstating what happened when I flipped the switch - I just don’t have any experience to know if that was significant or not. I added some pics to my original post. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My obligatory "get well-rounded knowledge" statement: the scenic way is to find an accessible-feeling book on the subject and read it through. Google is dangerous, that will leave you with swiss cheese knowledge. It only answers questions, and you need a well-rounded primer to *know which questions to ask*.

Anyway you are on the right track.  Your measurements at the switch are valuable, and normal.  The reason the readings surprise you (especially re: neutral) is that **switches don't use neutral**. That wire is not neutral.  They connect (or don't) two wire functions: *always-hot*, and *switched-hot*.  Neutral is not in play on a switch, unless it's a modern smart switch.

Voltage will always be zero (ish) across a switch with a broken lamp.  If the switch is on, the two terminals are both 120V.  If off, always-hot is 120V and switched-hot is unconnected/isolated becuse the lamp is broken, so no voltage between them.  If the lamp was working, it would pull the switched-hot line toward neutral, so you'd see 120V across the open (gapped) switch.

Powering back up to check the voltage across the bare wires outside is a reasonable next step, just be careful.  120V across them would indicate a fixture fault, 0V would reveal a wiring fault.

---

* most authorities think changing a light switch, receptacle or light fixture is too small a job to justify pulling a permit, so I interpret that as "too small to justify hiring an electrician", hence, handyman.

Comment: Thank you for your input - much appreciated. I’m just trying to learn a few basics but you’re probably right that Google can be dangerous in certain respects when it comes to this. I added some pictures to my original post

Comment: I mis read the question, was thinking OP was measuring at the fixture not the switch.+

Comment: just tested the voltage of the wires outside and they read 0V

Comment: @Dave oh dear.  If breaker and switch were on at that time, that indicates a problem witheiring, possibly at a splice which is accessible.  Was any recent construction done that might've put a nail through the cable?

Comment: @Harper nevermind...I just flipped the switch on and tested the outside wires (one on the white and one of the black) and got around 120V. So does that mean there's a problem with the fixture? It looks like I'm getting 120V outside?

Comment: @EdBeal I just flipped the switch on and tested the outside wires (one probe on black and the other on white) and got 120V. So does that mean my fixture is bad??

Comment: Yeah, that's assuredly a fixture problem.  Sounds like you're in the homestretch.  Great time to consider an LED bulbless fixture. Either buy top quality... or cheap Chinese, I have had good luck with LEDWholesalers, about 30% more than the cheapest Chinese but they work 5 years later.  Avoid CFL fluorescents, that ship has sailed.

Comment: Yes if you have 120v the fixture is bad or you connected it backwards some fixtures the neutral actually connects to the frame (older fixtures) the hot should go to the center conductor and the neutral should connect to the shell or threaded part. If going with LED's find ones that are DLC approved prior to doing this I had high failure rates. With DLC approved lamps the few that did fail were replaced or I received a credit.

Comment: @Harper Or could I have botched the installation? I was struggling getting the wires from the fixture to fit into the wire nut with the other wire. Any suggestions on the easiest way to work a wire nut? The wire from the fixture kept wanting to slide out of the wire nut. If it does turn out to be a bad fixture, I'll take a look at LED bulbless fixtures - I don't know anything about them. Thanks for your help

Comment: Yeah, old wire nuts are garbage generally. The new ones are much more evolved.  Electricians swear by Ideal brand.  Square up the wires and roughly straighten them, then twist like you mean it!  Clockwise like a bolt.

Comment: @EdBeal I'm having trouble getting the wires from the fixture connected to the wire nut with the wire from the inside. The wire nut I was using is all plastic on the inside. Why do some wire nuts have all plastic while others will have metal inside?  The wire from the fixture wants to keep fraying when tightening

Comment: @Harper so don't try to bend the wires around each other before putting them into the wire nut? I was trying to do that. Should I line them vertically next to each other and then twist the nut on? The nut I"m using is all plastic on the inside. Why do some have metal on the inside?

Comment: @Dave yeah, I don't bother pretwisting them, that'll happen pretty definitely.  All the ones I see have metal insides, *it's possible that an all-plastic inside one has had its metal bit fall out*

Comment: @Dave it's also important to use the right size of nut.  Officially they have a lot of range, but I prefer to be near the center of that range.  Orange for one #14 and a lighter fixture wire, yellow for 2-3 #14s or 2 #12s, red for larger.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86983/discussion-between-dave-and-harper).

Answer (score 0):

*edit - I don't think I am following the description of the problem in the question and deleted previous answer*

A much more detailed description of the problem - probably with pictures - would be necessary to make any suggestions.  Might be best to call in someone to look at this for you.

Comment: The switch has a black and a red wire going into it - does that mean anything? So I don't have a neutral wire on the switch? I wired it the same way that the previous switch was. Should I do any additional tests? Does it seem like I have voltage going into the switch properly?

Comment: @Dave - I am afraid I may not be clear on your original description.  I am going to edit my answer.

Comment: I just added some pictures